# How can we get the older state of a contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

What I have

- I have my private ehtereum chain running on an AWS EC2 instance.
- I am able to deploy contracts on my private chain.
- I am able to call functions of smart contract.

I am using truffle and react.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract NDA {
bytes32  party1name;
bytes32  party2name;

function NDA(bytes32 _party1name) {
     party1name = _party1name;
}

function SetParty2(bytes32 _party2name) {
     party2name = _party2name;
}

function get() constant returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
    return (party1name, party2name);
}
}
```

The above contract saves the 2 parties involved in a contract.
I am planning not to make a new contract everytime for 2 new parties but use the same contract as template and serve them from transactions which they do when they go in contract with each other.

To do so I should be able to go through the list of transactions of state update under that contract address for the specified user.

How can I travel back to an older state of a contract and fetch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a struct like

`struct Pair{
  bytes32 party1name;
  bytes32 party2name;
}`

And then have either an array or a mapping to store previous structs. You can have a variable like `Pair currentPair` if you want to easily retrieve the most recent one. I'm a little unsure of exactly what you are asking, but I think that this, or some variant of this, would be the best way.